# Why extensions are not reflected when they are installed in the directory structure

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento and got it installed on MAC. I have installed the "displaze protoshow slideshow" extension. I can see in the my connect that is installed properly and even in admin panel, I create an menu option for it. When I follow all the steps(this include the configuration line needed to be copied on home page in CMS) to get the banner on my home page, It is not displaying on front end. When I searched in the root directory, I can not find app/frontend/default/default/template/displaze.

I searched the whole directory structure but could not find it. So it will be great if some one could help me how to get this working.

Comment: Might have more luck on magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: As I understand form your query, you need to clear system caches and try again

Comment: I have disabled the cache before trying it.